# Is there some functionality to log/calculate time latencies of modules in spring weblfux? For e.g. using @Timed annotation

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I would like to know is there, or can we make use of any functionality to log the actual time taken by a function returning Mono/Flux? For example something like creating a @Timed annotation to log the actual time taken by it.
I know the function return type being Flux/Mono, so it should return immediately so that is why I wanna know if we can actually do something like this so that we can know which modules/sub-modules are taking how much time?

We want to migrate our blocking spring-boot service to spring webflux, so going through all the possible options we have for better understanding.

P.S. I am new To reactive programming, still learning the paradigm.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `metrics()` operator to time a publisher. You can combine this with the `name()` and `tags()` operators to customise the metrics that get published.

```
listenToEvents()
   .name("events") 
   .tag("source", "kafka")
   .metrics() 
   .doOnNext(event -> log.info("Received {}", event))
   .delayUntil(this::processEvent)
   .subscribe();
```

[Publisher metrics docs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_publisher_metrics)

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain a bit further about how do I retrieve these metrics? I read the docs and they say you must include micrometer to your dependencies, but after that, they say nothing about viewing the metrics?? I added this.

<dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: had to include, spring-boot-starter-actuator dependency to the class path to be able to hit the end point /actuator/metrics to view my metric, I saw there is one [name].flow.duration which shows maximum and total time, but can we have percentiles like 95, 99 etc or some more information around times??

Comment: have you taken a read through the spring actuator docs? This may be a good starting point - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#per-meter-properties